# Advice needed for super low noise motor 15-30 rpm motor for diy project

Tags: dc-motor, noise, motor-controller, rpm

I am doing a project where i have to rotate a hardboard disc of 20 inch diameter using a motor.

The disc is about a 1lb heavy. My current set up is using a 12V 20rpm DC motor from Amazon store:

https://a.co/d/7vR4DVX

However the problem is these motors emit loud noise, i measured ~ 45-55 db on soundmeter app.

I need something in the range 10-30db maximum, since the set up will be inside library/quite room. Basically as quite as it gets, still the motor has to be powerful enough to drive the 1lb disc. 15-30 RPM is fine.

Earlier I have tried using higher rpm motors 50-100 rpm and running them at low voltage (instead of 12V used 9v or 6v) , but they stop after running an hour. I need a runtime of at least 5-6 continuous hours for this project.

I have tested multiple 12V DC motors from different manufacturers on Amazon, but the one i have tested have same noise problem. I have been restricting to dc motors as i have worked with them the most and already have a 12V power supply.

One of the DC motor I found was low noise ~30 db but it runs at 3000rpm which is too high, even mounting with disc it spins way too fast at 3V lowest voltage setting https://a.co/d/fCzJUKI

I was thinking if DC motor PCM speed control units will help, but my best guess is they also decrease voltage so motor will have trouble to drive the load under resistance.

I am pretty new to these kind of projects, so please help me decide what kind of motor will suit this project.

Many thanks!

Comment: Think *audio turntable*.

Comment: Large inherently slow motor with plastic gears if necessary; the fewer the better. If you can mate a small pinion to the a large gear running around the entire diameter of your setup that is best. Belts work too. Don't drive from the center. Electronic speed control won't increase a motor's torque. If you rely solely on that you need a large motor that can direct drive to begin with at slow speeds (lots of poles).

Comment: You could probably also make some muscle wire finger mechanism to ratchet walk your disc along since it doesn't sound like extreme continuity really matters (art project?). Takes a more engineering though. That would be dead silent and be super cool.

Comment: Instead of a gear motor build a reduction system with pulleys and belts - they’re much quieter.

Comment: Synchronous AC [timer motors](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81lzptyqTSL._SX522_.jpg)  are low RPM and low noise. However they generally operate from mains voltage, which may be an  issue for you.